# How can I add dependency injection after the fact?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection

I have learned a lot developing my current android app, enough to see that I made some mistakes.  For example I now know that all the `new Blah(...)` statements below are bad from a test point of view.  Are there established techniques to safely migrate existing code like this to use a form of dependency injection?  By "safe" I mean low likely hood to break by app. I was thinking of just adding setter methods for each dependency so that I could pass in mock objects during test, but that seems a bit hackish.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    System.out.println("creating the LocationMonitorService");
    mBus = BusProvider.getInstance();
    mBus.register(this);
    markerRequestTimer = new GetMarkerRequestTimer(10*60000,10000);
    pushRequestTimer = new PushRequestTimer(10*60000,60000);
    deviceLocationClient = new DeviceLocationClient(this);
    gcmKeepAliveIntent = new Intent("com.gmail.npnster.first_project.gcmKeepAlive");
    gcmKeepAlivePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, gcmKeepAliveIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, 4*60*1000, gcmKeepAlivePendingIntent);


}

class GetMarkerRequestTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public GetMarkerRequestTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        System.out.println("requesting new markers from server");
        mBus.post(new GetMapMarkersRequest());

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        System.out.println("time out reached ending request for markers from the server");  


    }

}
```

Comment: What injection framework are you using? Roboguice?

Comment: My first thoughts were Dager, but I would consider either

Comment: Either one is fine. Dagger is more focused towards Android (built for speed). Roboguice has a bit more to offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing you are on android, I am assuming you use [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/). If using Guice, replace ObjectGraph with Injector. The rest is the same.

I haven't had to do this refactoring on android before but have done it in server-side java projects. You can incrementally add dependency injection. Starting with:

```
class A {
  B b = new B();
}

class B {
  C c = new C();
}

class C {
}
```

Now let's assume we want to refactor B to use DI, but without changing the structure of A.

Create a new ObjectGraph somewhere central. Make it static and public (bad in general, good for incremental transition)

```
public void onCreate()  {
    ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MyModule());
    Global.objectGraph = objectGraph; //Where global is just a class with a public static field called objectGraph
    MyApp app = objectGraph.get(App.class);
    ...
  }
```

So now you can refactor B:

```
class B {
  private final C c;
  @Inject
  B(C c) {
      this.c = c;
  }
}
```

B is now injected and testable. To get rid of the new call in A, replace

```
new B()
```

with

```
Global.objectGraph.get(B.class)
```

Which effectively gives you a fully refactored B and a backwards-compatible A. When, if ever you get rid of all the static references to the global object graph, you can delete it.

Comment: I think I would like to follow this approach.  I had just started reading about Dager, but the whole concept is new to me.  Could you possibly show what you think the Module class for this example might look like?  I think it would help me a lot.

Comment: I've used the approach before, on a very large project and it worked well. It was in guice though, and I have only briefly touched Dagger. For simple DI, you probably don't need a module, so just ObjectGraph.create(), should get you started. I would suggest reading carefully the Dagger docs to get a feel of how to do everything. The main point I was trying to get across is the incremental adding of DI, and accessing a static injector in places you are not ready to refactor.

Comment: I have not forgotten about this answer, I am still working through some of the details.  I think I see where you are going with this.  I think you have provided some very good “breadcrumbs” to follow. When I do get through this I will probably comeback and edit your answer with some more details before I accept it.  I am finding this DI/Dagger stuff to be a bit over my head.